# Regex find text between two hash comments

Tags: regex

I want to find and replace text between to hash comments. e.g I want to find if there is a text something like below within **#string_start** and **#string_end**

```
#string_start 
this could be any text here
and here
#string_end
```

I tried this code but it didn't work and I know I am not using the corrent syntax due to my lack of regex knowledge.

```
\#string_start(.*?)\#string_end
```

Comment: I have added the code, I want #string_start and #string_end to be hard coded.

Comment: You can use this regex: `#string_start([\s\S]*?)#string_end`

Comment: Thanks anubhava, you save my day.

Comment: What is your host language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#string_start\n([\s\S]*?)#string_end
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/61

Comment: Hi, thanks but I want to #string_start  and #string_end to be hard coded.